# What will happen if an ACTIVE Bundle in OSGi is Installed again?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

What happens is a bundle which is already in ACTIVE is installed and started again. Will it again go to first INSTALLED and then ACTIVE state?

Comment: You can't install two bundles with the same symbolicName/version

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to install a bundle using an existing location, then the framework will simply return the current Bundle object for that location. If you try to install the same bundle using a different location, you will get an installation error due to duplicate bundle symbolic name and bundle version.